# Blender throwing warning while adding threejs addon

Tags: three.js, blender

I am not a 3d modeller, and new to jeeliz face filter git library. I am trying to convert one necklest.gltf 3d model to threejs(json format) using below link.

[Steps for adding threejs exporter in blender](https://medium.com/@StartupJeeliz/creating-a-snapchat-like-filter-with-jeelizs-facefilter-api-part-1-creating-your-first-filter-1e7a5000543c)

All the steps I have followed but at the end when I am checking the checkbox to enable it, its saying "upgrade to 2.8x req". 
I am using blender 2.81a. I have tested on 2.81 also still not working.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to use the JSON Blender exporter anymore. Export your models to `glTF` instead and then use `THREE.GLTFLoader`. Notice that the exporter was removed with `R93` in May 2018. Just three month after the article at `medium.com` was published.

`three.js R113`

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Mugen's answer, the Blender Three.js JSON exporter was written for the previous version of Blender 2.7x. When Blender 2.8 came out, it revamped almost every aspect of its engine, and the JSON exporter is no longer supported. However, it's been replaced with a much more efficient exporter you can find in `File > Export > glTF 2.0`. You can read about it [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/io_scene_gltf2.html?highlight=gltf).

Once you have exported your GLTF file, you can import it into Three.js with [`THREE.GLTFLoader`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader).